# How to use localized MediaItem title and album using audio_service on Flutter

Tags: flutter, audio

I'm using [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) package in my Flutter app.
In all the examples `MediaItem`s either appear in the class extended from `BackgroundAudioTask` or passed from another class but they're hard-coded at the end..

In my project I only have one `MediaItem` (regardless of the played sound) and I would like to use localized strings in that `MediaItem`.

The problem is the `BackgroundAudioTask` won't give you a `BuildContext`, so you can't get localized strings from your `BackgroundAudioTask`.

So far I tried overriding `onUpdateMediaItem` in my `BackgroundAudioTask` like so:

```dart
@override
onUpdateMediaItem(MediaItem mediaItem) async {
  AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
}
```

and setting the MediaItem outside of `BackgroundAudioTask`, like so:

```dart
final mediaItem = MediaItem(
    id: "my-fixed-id",
    album: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('media_item_album'),
    title: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('media_item_title'),
);
AudioService.updateMediaItem(mediaItem);
```

The problem is I don't know where to put this second block of code. I can't put it inside my App class because localizations are not initialized there yet and I'm not sure if it makes sense to put it in a page screen since this `MediaItem`s are for the service and shouldn't suppose to be tied to a screen.

Can you help me use localized strings for `MediaItem`s?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

In my background task:

```dart
@override
Future<void> onUpdateMediaItem(MediaItem mediaItem) async {
  AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
}
```

In my `HomePage` I listened to `running` event stream, get the string values and then set the media item:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _setMediaItem();
}

void _setMediaItem() {
  AudioService.runningStream.listen((bool isRunning) {
    if (isRunning) {
      AudioService.updateMediaItem(
        MediaItem(
          id: "ambiance-sound-mix",
          album: AppLocalizations.of(context).getString("media_item_album"),
          title: AppLocalizations.of(context).getString("media_item_title"),
        ),
      );
    }
  });
}
```

PS:
I also tried switching to [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) thinking that would solve the issue since it doesn't require a `BuildContext` to look-up string values. However that didn't work because when you try to get string values from audio_service's `BackgroundAudioTask`, EasyLocalization fails because it can't access its `instance` with loaded strings and try to get strings from an empty strings map..